# Remove newline if inside doublequote, otherwise print the line

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I need to remove newlines from a double quoted string, but persisting lines that do not have double quote.

I have this sample:

```
s = '''"content of row 1"
"content of row 2 
 continues here"
content of row 3'''
```

When I use this piece of code:

```
row_pattern = '''"[^"]*"'''
row = re.compile(row_pattern, flags = re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)

for i, r in enumerate(row.finditer(s)):
    string = r.group().replace('\n', '')
    print(f'{i} {string}')
```

I get this:

```
0 "content of row 1"
1 "content of row 2  continues here"
```

But my desired output is this:

```
0 "content of row 1"
1 "content of row 2  continues here"
2 content of row 3
```

Comment: Just to make it clear: if the line starts with and ends with `"`, it must be skipped and else, the next line without leading/trailing `"` should be appended to the current one, right?

Comment: Check https://ideone.com/qraJ4L

Comment: I've made some modification. My sample was indeed confusing.

Comment: Ah, so it is just `re.sub(r'"[^"]*"', lambda x: x.group().replace('\n', ' '), s)`